# Правильное использование scrollview в MVVM Android

Tags: android, mvvm, imageview, viewmodel, scrollview

Я студент, только начал изучать паттерн MVVM. С примитивным обновлением текста на вьюшках с использованием подписки при помощи Oberverа разобрался легко. Но возникли проблемы со следуйщим:
Есть scrollview с набором imageview'ов, который меняется в зависимости от действий пользователя. Так как ViewModel не должна содержать никаких "андоидовых элементов", то и список imageview'ов там хранить нельзя. Как тогда правильно организовать взаимодействие между активностью и ViewModel? И правильный ли я вообще паттерн выбрал?

Comment: не ясно, как вообще связаны ViewModel и ScrollView у вас. ViewModel должна хранить только данные. данные изменяются, дергаются Observer'ы и вы уже что-то делаете во View. можете подробнее описать ваши пожелания и приложить код.

Comment: А вы не путаете случайно ScrollView с ListView или RecycleView? Потому что первый ничего особенного с точки зрения наполнения данными не представляет.